# Is there any way to communicate to main layout of blazor pages

Tags: c#, components, blazor, blazor-server-side

Here I want to pass some title to the mainlayout.razor page so that my components or pages can update the title of header. Is there any possible way in blazor to do this ? Any help will be appreciated.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4 bg-success">
            <button onclick="toggleNav()">
                <span class="oi oi-menu"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="text-center">
                hey there
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>

@code
{

}
```

and my child component is a router page with @page directive to navigate between pages i want that component to update this mainlayout is there any possible way ? Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards,

Comment: Have you looked at the `<Title>` component?   https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/23833

Comment: @KirkWoll that is something else and i have already used that for window title

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should wrap the view portion of the MainLayout component with the CascadingValue component whose value is a reference to the MainLayout itself, so that you can reference the MainLayout component, say, from the Counter component, from which you assign a value string to the property
Title defined in the MainLayout component. This property also contain a call to the StateHasChanged method to refresh the display...

```
 @page "/counter"



// Gets a reference to the MainLayout component
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout Layout { get; set; }


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Layout.Title = "Greetings from Counter";

    }
```

### MainLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <NavMenu />
        </div>

        <div class="main">
            <div class="top-row px-4">
                @Title
                <LoginDisplay />
                <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
            </div>

            <div class="content px-4">
                @Body
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</CascadingValue>

@code
{
    private string title;

    public string Title
    {
        get => title;
        set
        {
            title = value;
            InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing work like butter. But can you please explain how you figured out to do this ? Actually cascading params according to docs say that we can pass params from ancestors to decestors

Comment: See option 2 in Chris Sainty's [3 Ways to Communicate Between Components in Blazor](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/) article for another explanation of this approach.

Comment: @Humza Malik MindFreak, you can pass parameters downstream, from parent to children, and that exactly what I did. Note: The Title property is not a parameter, if you happened to refer to it.

Comment: error VSTHRD110: Observe the awaitable result of this method call by awaiting it, assigning to a variable, or passing it to another method.

C# v6.0.403

Answer (score 4):

From **.Net 8** (available on Nov. 2023), Blazor will support **[Section outlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/sections?view=aspnetcore-8.0)**, which are designed for this:

**_Imports.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Sections
```

**MainLayout.razor**

```
<SectionOutlet SectionName="page-title" />
```

**MyPage.razor**

```
<SectionContent SectionName="page-title">My Page Title</SectionContent>
```